# Deploy F# Azure Storage type provider to deploy to Azure web app

Tags: git, f#, azure-web-app-service, type-providers

I'm trying to use the Azure Storage type provider in my F# project:

```
Install-Package FSharp.Azure.StorageTypeProvider
```

It works locally, but when I deploy from my local Git repository to my Azure web app, I get the following errors

> remote: Updating branch 'master'.
>
> remote: Updating submodules.
>
> remote: Preparing deployment for commit id 'f67901b428'.
>
> remote: Generating deployment script.
>
> remote: Running deployment command...
>
> remote: Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
>
> remote: All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
>
> remote: All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
>
> remote:
>   D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5):
>   warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the
>   same dependent assembly.
>   [D:\home\site\repository\FlunSharp\FlunSharp.fsproj]
>
> remote: FSC : error FS3031: The type provider
>   'D:\home\site\repository\packages\FSharp.Azure.StorageTypeProvider.1.2.0\lib\net40\FSharp.Azure.StorageTypeProvider.dll'
>   reported an error: Assembly attribute 'TypeProviderAssemblyAttribute'
>   refers to a designer assembly 'FSharp.Azure.StorageTypeProvider' which
>   cannot be loaded or doesn't exist. Could not load file or assembly
>   'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.
>   [D:\home\site\repository\FlunSharp\FlunSharp.fsproj]
>
> remote: FSC : warning FS3005: Referenced assembly
>   'D:\home\site\repository\packages\FSharp.Azure.StorageTypeProvider.1.2.0\lib\net40\FSharp.Azure.StorageTypeProvider.dll'
>   has assembly level attribute
>   'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.TypeProviderAssemblyAttribute'
>   but no public type provider classes were found
>   [D:\home\site\repository\FlunSharp\FlunSharp.fsproj]
>
> remote: Failed exitCode=1,
>   command="D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"
>   "D:\home\site\repository\FlunSharp\FlunSharp.fsproj" /nologo
>   /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder
>   /p:_PackageTempDir="D:\local\Temp\3ec76803-496c-41df-ad73-f8bc79256ad9";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release
>   /p:SolutionDir="D:\home\site\repository.\"
>
> remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
>
> remote:
>
> remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment
>   to website failed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have a sample repo that show this error? I tried to add that TypeProvider into a project of mine, and it built fine on git deployment. Also what runtime are you targeting and do you have any other packages in your packages.config?

Comment: https://github.com/Overlord-Zurg/AzureTypeProviderSample. I'm targetting F# 3.1, .NET 4.5.1, and it's a WebSharper "Client-Server Web Application".

Comment: huh, I just created a brand new site, and git pushed that repo to the site, and it deployed successfully. do you have anything custom on your site?

Comment: though, you have a version of the [FSharp runtime checked into the repo](https://github.com/Overlord-Zurg/AzureTypeProviderSample/tree/master/AzureTypeProviderSample2/bin) it shouldn't affect anything, but you may wanna consider a [`.gitignore` file that looks like this](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore)

Comment: I just created a project of type "F# MVC 5" from the online templates and installed the Type Provider package, and it gave the same error. I did the same as you -- brand new "Web App", no settings changed. I'll try the .gitignore thing.

Comment: It looks like the thing I uploaded to GitHub was not at all what I meant to, and doesn't even have the package installed. I'll provide a better example momentarily. I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81464/discussion-between-overlord-zurg-and-ahmelsayed).

Comment: https://github.com/Overlord-Zurg/AzureTypeProviderSample now contains the WebSharper project with the StorageTypeProvider package that gives the error when deployed to Azure.

Answer (score 1):

We talked about this in the [chat here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81464/discussion-between-overlord-zurg-and-ahmelsayed)

Basically this was an issue in how MSBuild on the server detects the right F# compiler to build the project with (3.0 vs 3.1)

A work around is to specify another MSBuild version through setting an app setting on the site that looks like this
`MSBUILD_PATH = D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe`

However, the right fix should go in the `fsproj` file. In particular this section

```
<!-- F# targets -->
<Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '11.0'">
      <PropertyGroup Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\..\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets')">
          <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\..\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
        <PropertyGroup Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets')">
            <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
        </PropertyGroup>
   </Otherwise>
</Choose>
<Import Project="$(FSharpTargetsPath)" />
```

Should be updated to

```
<!-- F# targets -->
<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion>12.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
    <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(FSharpTargetsPath)" />
```

I think this is an issue with WebSharper templates that don't set the correct visual studio version in the project file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect you are hitting a similar issue to what I was hitting deploying F# to Azure.  The issue I was running into is that the build system did not pick up the F# references correctly.  I had to manually add the reference to the path, and manually move the .dll references into the output path of the final solution.

http://indiedevspot.com/2015/02/18/deploying-f-web-job-to-azure/